# NameError: global name 'myExample2' is not defined # modules

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, module

Here is my `example.py` file:

```
from myimport import *
def main():
    myimport2 = myimport(10)
    myimport2.myExample() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And here is `myimport.py` file:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
    def myExample(self):
        result = myExample2(self.number) - self.number
        print(result)
    def myExample2(num):
        return num*num
```

When I run `example.py` file, i have the following error:

```
NameError: global name 'myExample2' is not defined
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: you need `myExample2(self, num)` and then refer to it as `self.myExample2()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a simple fix to your code.

```
from myimport import myClass #import the class you needed

def main():
    myClassInstance = myClass(10) #Create an instance of that class
    myClassInstance.myExample() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the `myimport.py`:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
    def myExample(self):
        result = self.myExample2(self.number) - self.number
        print(result)
    def myExample2(self, num): #the instance object is always needed 
        #as the first argument in a class method
        return num*num
```

Answer (score 9):

I see two errors in you code:

1. You need to call `myExample2` as `self.myExample2(...)`
2. You need to add `self` when defining myExample2: `def myExample2(self, num): ...`

Answer (score 1):

First, I agree in with alKid's answer.  This is really more a comment on the question than an answer, but I don't have the reputation to comment.

My comment:

**The global name that causes the error is `myImport` not `myExample2`**

Explanation:

The full error message generated by my Python 2.7 is:

```
Message File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
    <module>    C:\xxx\example.py   7       
    main    C:\xxx\example.py   3       
NameError: global name 'myimport' is not defined
```

I found this question when I was trying to track down an obscure "global name not defined" error in my own code.  Because the error message in the question is incorrect, I ended up more confused.  When I actually ran the code and saw the actual error, it all made sense.

I hope this prevents anyone finding this thread from having the same problem I did.  If someone with more reputation than I wants to turn this into a comment or fix the question, please feel free.

Comment: To all those who have chastised me for not answering a question, I apologize.  **TLDR:  The code sample in the question does not produce the error.  Question is unanswerable!**

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of the `myClass` class, and not the instance of the whole module(and i edit variables names to be less awful):

```
from myimport import *
def main():
    #myobj = myimport.myClass(10)
    # the next string is similar to above, you can do both ways
    myobj = myClass(10)
    myobj.myExample() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are correct, I wonder if there is really a need for `myExample2()` being a method. You could as well implement it standalone:

```
def myExample2(num):
    return num*num

class myClass:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
    def myExample(self):
        result = myExample2(self.number) - self.number
        print(result)
```

Or, if you want to keep your namespace clean, implement it as a method, but as it doesn't need `self`, as a `@staticmethod`:

```
def myExample2(num):
    return num*num

class myClass:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
    def myExample(self):
        result = self.myExample2(self.number) - self.number
        print(result)
    @staticmethod
    def myExample2(num):
        return num*num
```